# How to use the RETURNING update query into the DQL

Tags: php, doctrine-orm, zend-framework2, dql

I'm trying to run these following simple query (it works in postgresql)

```
update ja_clients set ref_inc_num = ref_inc_num + 1  where id = 43933 returning ref_inc_num;
```

into DQL

```
$query = $this->entityManager->createQuery();
            $query->setDQL("UPDATE Geoop\Core\Entity\Account a SET a.jobReferenceNumber__ = a.jobReferenceNumber__ + 1  WHERE a.id = :accountId  RETURNING a.jobReferenceNumber__");
            $query->setParameter('accountId', $account->getId());
            $total = $query->getSingleScalarResult();
```

but it doesn't work retuning this error:

```
#30 /var/www/geoop_api/vendor/doctrine/orm/lib/Doctrine/ORM/Query/Parser.php (line 861): Doctrine\ORM\Query\Parser->syntaxError(end of string)
#31 /var/www/geoop_api/vendor/doctrine/orm/lib/Doctrine/ORM/Query/Parser.php (line 448): Doctrine\ORM\Query\QueryException::dqlError(UPDATE Geoop\Core\Entity\Account a SET a.jobReferenceNumber__ = a.jobReferenceNumber__ + 1  WHERE a.id = :accountId  RETURNING a.id as id)
```

Answer (score 1):

DQL does not support the `RETURNING` clause, so you need to [use native SQL](https://www.doctrine-project.org/projects/doctrine-orm/en/2.6/reference/native-sql.html). You will also have to [create a result set mapping](https://www.doctrine-project.org/projects/doctrine-orm/en/2.6/reference/native-sql.html#the-resultsetmapping).

NOTE: I don't know the actual names of your table and columns, but assuming they are named the same as your entity and properties, this will work:

```php
$rsm = new \Doctrine\ORM\Query\ResultSetMapping();
$rsm->addScalarResult('jobReferenceNumber', 'jobReferenceNumber');

$sql = "
    UPDATE account a
    SET a.jobReferenceNumber = a.jobReferenceNumber + 1
    WHERE a.id = :accountId
    RETURNING a.jobReferenceNumber
";

$query = $this->entityManager->createNativeQuery($sql, $rsm);
$query->setParameter('accountId', $account->getId());
$total = $query->getSingleScalarResult();
```

You may need to correct the table and column names in my example. When using native SQL, you have to use the actual names in the database, not the names of entity and properties. Also, remember that postgres converts all object names to upper case unless they are quoted.

Answer (score 0):

thanks for the insight :) this is working now

Heres my updated code :
Above the class i use the ResultSetMapping

```
use Doctrine\ORM\Query\ResultSetMapping;

$rsm = new ResultSetMapping();
$rsm->addScalarResult('ref_inc_num', 'ref_inc_num');
$sql = "
UPDATE ja_clients
SET ref_inc_num = ref_inc_num + 1
WHERE id = :clientId
RETURNING ref_inc_num
";
$query = $this->entityManager->createNativeQuery($sql, $rsm);
$query->setParameter('clientId', $account->getId());
$refNum = $query->getSingleScalarResult();
```

Comment: How is your answer different from [the answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/55528206/1155833) by patrick3853, apart from some names?